# Are foreigners who buy UK ETFs subjected to a withholding tax?

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, etf, bonds, dividends

Currently, when a foreigner buys U.S ETFs, the dividends or income (in the case of bond ETF) will be taxed at 30%. Suppose a foreigner, say an American or Singaporean, buys a UK bond ETF. Is there a similar withholding tax that will be slapped on the foreigner?